# Power Query and Hive

Tags: hive, odbc, powerquery

I am testing Power Query with Hive using a Horntonworks ODBC driver. Other than the query take forever, I am perplexed by why so many jobs are initiated for a simple operations.

Furthermore group by appears to fail when counting or summing numbers.

Would welcome feedback from other users.

Cheers

Comment: Can you please provide us more details? What kind of failure do you get? It would help us fix the issue if you can send us a frown email :)

About the performance, Hive itself is pretty slow on ad hoc queries. If you can set up an Impala on your Hive (I'm not sure how that happens) and use an Impala driver, that will make a big difference performance-wise. http://hortonworks.com/blog/impala-vs-hive-performance-benchmark/

Comment: we have support from horntonworks - would it be easier  to raise it using that channel?

Comment: I think so, but I can't talk on behalf of them :) But with the knowledge I have (which is not much, really) I can say that Impala is what you need.

Comment: Also, I never talked to a Power Query or Power BI user that wants to connect Hive/Impala before, I always wanted to ask this question :) : Are you using complex types? Will you need to require to access to a table's complex typed columns? Thanks